# Why should I mark all fields private in immutable classes?

Tags: java, immutability

From JDK documentation:

> Don't provide "setter" methods — methods that modify fields or objects
>   referred to by fields. Make all fields final and private. Don't allow
>   subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to
>   declare the class as final. A more sophisticated approach is to make
>   the constructor private and construct instances in factory methods. If
>   the instance fields include references to mutable objects, don't allow
>   those objects to be changed: Don't provide methods that modify the
>   mutable objects. Don't share references to the mutable objects. Never
>   store references to external, mutable objects passed to the
>   constructor; if necessary, create copies, and store references to the
>   copies. Similarly, create copies of your internal mutable objects when
>   necessary to avoid returning the originals in your methods.

example:

```
final public class ImmutableRGB {

    // Values must be between 0 and 255.
    final private int red;
    final private int green;
    final private int blue;
    final private String name;

    private void check(int red,
                       int green,
                       int blue) {
        if (red < 0 || red > 255
            || green < 0 || green > 255
            || blue < 0 || blue > 255) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public ImmutableRGB(int red,
                        int green,
                        int blue,
                        String name) {
        check(red, green, blue);
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getRGB() {
        return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ImmutableRGB invert() {
        return new ImmutableRGB(255 - red,
                       255 - green,
                       255 - blue,
                       "Inverse of " + name);
    }
}
```

Please, explain why should l mark fields as private?

Comment: @KevinEsche if the fields are `final` they cannot be modified even if the fields are not `private`.

Comment: Apart of this, in order to maintain the immutability of the class, marking an object reference field `final` won't make it immutable, make sure the class of that object reference is immutable as well.

Comment: Because if you don't set the field as private, any other class can alter the field by simply doing `Class.immutable_field = whatever` and you field has been successfuly mutated, and you now possibly have a bug. Congratulations.

Comment: @TheLaw again, this cannot happen since the field is marked as `final`...

Comment: An immutable class is one in which state can't change. In your case the class is immutable regardless of the accessibility to the fields.  But that is only because both the int and String fields are immutable.  If they were not immutable you would run into issues.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i am blind, didn´t see the final ...